# Load large amount of data from the query result in memory in Python

Tags: python, pandas

**What I want to do?**

Get count of distinct rows of the table based on different possible column combinations. E.g. Say, a table has columns col1, col2, col3, col4, I would like to get counts of all different combinations of these 4 columns

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT <columns combinations>) FROM Table);
```

columns combinations can be:

- col1
- col2
- col3
- col4
- col1, col2
- col1, col3
- col1, col4
- col1, col2, col3
- and so on.

If I do this by running query for each possible combinations in  Python, it would be lot of queries that I need to run in Python which will be very slow.

**What I tried and didn't work:**

Load this data in memory and then get the row counts for each possible column combinations. The number of rows in a table are around 100M and number of possible cols is around 20 columns. Total size of data is around 5GB. The machine I am running these computations on is a 16GB RAM and 8 CPUs.

When I tried to load this data in pandas dataframe, then putting the data in dataframe doesn't finish in few hours. It looks like the bottleneck. Also, I don't know how slow the operation to get count from data frame would be.

Is there any better way to load this data in memory, where I can run count computations very fast? Or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in SQL or python? Because all I see is SQL code...

Comment: I don't know what language SQL or Python you are trying to do, but my guess is you are doing it wrong and inefficiently. 20 columns with all the combinations would result in `1,048,575` cols. If one col has 1MB of data, this would give you from 20MB table explode to 1GB table. I suggest you to find other solution

Comment: Also, there should only be 15 combinations of 4, not 20.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The brute force approach with no loading of data in dataframe is running SQL queries for all possible combinations of columns from Python code.

Comment: What ***code*** have you used to try and solve this problem in python?

Comment: 4 columns was just an example to show what do I mean by possible combinations. In reality, the table contains like 20 columns.

Comment: There are 1,048,575 combinations of 20... You need to re-evaluate whatever it is you're actually trying to do.